# Deadlocked queries cause an instant error for end-users, but are retried in other circumstances

Tags: smartgroups, deadlocks, errorhandling

We have a lot of smart groups, and consequently a lot of deadlocks. There's already [code in Civi](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/197/files) that detects deadlock Exceptions, and then retries the query a few times. This is really helpful - I have extra logging on this, and I can see that it prevents a lot of errors. But this code doesn't kick in for people directly using the UI - they get the 'unknown error' yellow-screen-of-death immediately. This can happen on exports, or when opening complex groups. I dug into this and sort-of know why it's happening:

- When a deadlock happens, an exception is thrown if `$GLOBALS['_PEAR_default_error_options'][1]` is set to 'exceptionHandler'. This exception triggers the code which retries the query.
- An exception is **not** thrown if `$GLOBALS['_PEAR_default_error_options'][1]` is set to 'handle'.
- `$GLOBALS['_PEAR_default_error_options'][1]` is set to 'exceptionHandler' when you generate smart groups via the API, and in most other circumstances
- But `$GLOBALS['_PEAR_default_error_options'][1]` is set to 'handle' in the UI in general (?) - at least, it is on exports and when using 'Manage Groups'. So in this case no exception is raised. And if there's no exception, the try-catch blocks have nothing to work with and front-end users get 'unknown error' immediately.

I am happy to fund a fix for this, but I'm not sure what I'm getting myself into. Is this a bug, or is it an unfortunate consequence of how error handling needs to work for end users?

Comment: Can you share which CMS and which version of CiviCRM you are running?

Comment: WordPress and Civi 5.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to "hide" the problem when it happens, it might be safer/wiser to try to prevent it.

I like smartgroups and how powerful they are, but I found that it works better if I cache the results for a while (eg. a day) and rebuild the smart groups via the jobs.

Would it be acceptable to keep a "stalled" version of your groups for a while and avoid rebuilding them all the time in your case?

Also, you mention having a lot of smartgroups, it might be worthwhile creating a custom search that would run the queries you want when you need to use them instead of creating lots of smartgroups. We found it more performant and easier to maintain.

X+

Comment: We've done this to an extent, but we're heavy users of smart groups (well over 1000) and the staff make new ones every day. They would be quite confused / annoyed if their groups didn't update right away. We did some analysis of the most time consuming groups - as well as the 'base' groups that many others rely on - and turned these into regular groups that populate overnight. This helped a lot. To be honest I'm quite happy with the setup as it is: the deadlocks get caught and retried, and very rarely fail. It's just the UI deadlocks that are a difficulty.

Comment: I would be interested in how you analyzed the slowest smartgroups. We also experience deadlock problems with too many and too complex smartgroups

Comment: @RichardvanOosterhout we used a combination of two things. First we use New Relic monitoring, which lets us drill down into slow queries. Secondly I added basic time logging to Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache::load() - basically just starting a timer at the start of the function, stopping it at the end, and logging it along with the group ID. Quite revealing!

Comment: nice! would it be possible you can show me the code you inserted for that?

Comment: oops sorry - missed this. Email me at awest@humanism.org.uk and I'll send it over (just because it's not easy to put code in these comments)